# SQL-style linq queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, lambda

Hi I was wondering if it were possible to convert this SQL:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Age
FROM Persons p
```

To something like this:

```
var query = Sql
  .Select<Person>(p => p.Name, p.Age)
  .From<Persons>(p)
  .Run();
```

The `Person` and `Persons` classes would be created from the database structure (like with the [Reverse POCO Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838)).

The `Run()` method would take the preceding linq and generate the above SQL. As the linq style will follow the SQL structure it should be a case of iterating through the statements in order and using a `StringBuilder` to build the final query.

So my questions are Specifically:

`Select<Person>(p => p.Name, p.Age)`

1. Can an infinite number of properties be listed (like `param string[] names`)
2. Can those property names be extracted (the whole `p.name`)
3. Could those properties be static, and thus not have to create a `person` instance?

`.From<Persons>(p)`

1. can the type name in the `<>` brackets be extracted?
2. Can just a letter be specified here?

`.Run()`

1. Can the preceding structure be taken and turned into a string?
2. Would there be that much of a performance hit compared to simply inlining an SQL string?

Comment: Yes; that's entirely possible.  Look at micro-ORMs, which do exactly that.

Comment: I am with @SLaks on this. [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) is one example. Its main page also has references to other populate frameworks. You can google more, if needed.

Comment: Not to hijack the question, but why would/wouldn't EF be applicable here?

Comment: um... @SLaks & Neolisk:  It's only possible with them if you ignore the bottom 2/3rds of his question.

Comment: @JamesCurran: His first part is possible by abusing collection initializers, or with anonymous types.

Comment: @Neolisk: PetaPoco relies to much on inline SQL, whereas I am looking to keep all table+col names as types so compile time errors are possible if the db changes. DeeMac: EF causes enough headaches for me to ask this question. Something I'd want to be able to do is take a query from one of my DBA's and with minimal changes to the structure of it have it represented in C#. SLaks: is it possible to get any examples please?

Comment: It's either inline SQL (PetaPoco and others), or EF (and similar), cannot have both.

Comment: @LynchDev - which headaches? I've had no problems with it. I'm genuinely curious as to why people steer away from suggesting EF, I'm not asking rhetorically. I'd be interested to hear people's objections to it.